# ``Bring forth on'' in Gettysburg's Address

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The beginning of the first sentence of the *Gettysburg's Address* takes the form *Four score and seven years ago our fathers **brought forth on** this continent ...*. I found not the phrase *bring forth on*; I found the phrase *bring forth*. How should I understand the former phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On is not a part of the phrasal verb here, but a part of the location.

On this continent, here is probably an addition of information, do you have the next line?

Comment: Thanks very much. The next line is *a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.*

Comment: Then certainly it is... Brought forth a new nation.... Brought forth, on this continent, a new nation. An addition of information.

Comment: No worries, phrasals can be a royal pain!